# To add a sequence generated to the next table in java code

Tags: java, postgresql

I have the following data to enter

```
l_objPreparedStatement.setString(1, p_sEmailId);
String entrydate = p_mapAsOneEntryDTO.get(i).getEntryForDate();
String projectName = p_mapAsOneEntryDTO.get(i).getProjectName();
String taskNo = p_mapAsOneEntryDTO.get(i).getTaskNo();
String storyNo = p_mapAsOneEntryDTO.get(i).getStoryNo();
String storyTitle = p_mapAsOneEntryDTO.get(i).getStoryTitle();
String comment = p_mapAsOneEntryDTO.get(i).getComments();
String iterationNo = p_mapAsOneEntryDTO.get(i).getIterationNo();
float hrs = Float.parseFloat(p_mapAsOneEntryDTO.get(i).getWorkHours());
String subpro = p_mapAsOneEntryDTO.get(i).getSubProjectcat();
l_objPreparedStatement.setString(2, entrydate);
l_objPreparedStatement.setString(3, projectName);
l_objPreparedStatement.setString(4, taskNo);
l_objPreparedStatement.setString(5, storyNo);
l_objPreparedStatement.setString(6, storyTitle);
l_objPreparedStatement.setString(7, comment);
l_objPreparedStatement.setString(8, iterationNo);
l_objPreparedStatement.setFloat(9, hrs);
l_objPreparedStatement.setString(10, p_sLoggedUser);
l_objPreparedStatement.setString(11, p_sLoggedUser);
l_objPreparedStatement.setString(12, subpro);

l_objPreparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

the corresponding query is

```
"INSERT INTO ASONE_TASK_DETAIL (TASK_SID,EMAIL_ID,ENTRY_FOR_DATE,PROJECT_NAME,TASK_NO,STORY_NO,STORY_TITLE,COMMENTS, "
                + "ITERATION_NO,WORK_HOURS,TIMESTAMP,TRIGGER_TYPE,CREATED_BY, "
                + "CREATED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE,CATEGORY)VALUES(SQ_ASONE_TASK_DETAIL_ID.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,SYSDATE,'M',?,SYSDATE,?,SYSDATE,?) ";
```

The first value >SQ_ASONE_TASK_DETAIL_ID.NEXTVAL

i need to add it into the next query as id

how can i get this vaule from preparedStatement after the execute update command.

```
I tried

ResultSet resultSet = l_objPreparedStatement.executeQuery();
                    String taskId = String.valueOf(resultSet.getInt("TASK_SID"));
                    p_mapAsOneEntryDTO.get(i).setID(taskId);
```

but not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use `select SQ_ASONE_TASK_DETAIL_ID.NEXTVAL from dual` to get the sequence value before execute insert. Then put the value into the preperedStatement as a simple parameter in the insert and the following query